# What is the difference between an operation with foreach loop and LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, difference

I'm solving a problem, and I understood that these codes work in different ways, but I can't understand why the second one isn't correct and what's the difference.

```
public Person GetOldestMember()
{
    Person oldestPerson = people.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age).FirstOrDefault();

    return oldestPerson;
}
```

.

```
public Person GetOldestMember()
{
    Person oldestPerson = new Person(-1); //this is a constructor with parameter age

    foreach (Person person in people)
    {
        if (person.Age > oldestPerson.Age)
        {
            oldestPerson = person;
        }
    }

    return oldestPerson;
}
```

Comment: What's "incorrect" about it?  Are you getting a different result?  The main difference between the two that I see right away is that the first implementation will return `null` for an empty list while the second implementation will return a `Person` object for an empty list.

Comment: Note that you do not have to reorder a list to get the oldest or youngest person: linq has `Min` and `Max` which do what the names suggest

Comment: you really should explain what is "incorrect" about the second code example, otherwise you risk that this question gets closed as unclear

Comment: Other than the difference in behavior for an empty list, the only difference I can see is that the first performs notably slower than the second.  Ordering is a very poor means of getting the max value.

Comment: Either approach is flawed because `people` could contain multiple `Person` objects with the same oldest age.  They should return a collection of `Person` or be called `GetFirstOldestMember()`.

Comment: @BACON meh... just add a comment "if multiple people share the oldest age, the person returned is arbitrarily selected from that group" - sorted :)

Answer (score 6):

- LINQ is optimized for readability; it is easy to write, read, and understand
- but it isn't always *quite* as efficient; it can't exploit things like custom iterators, and may involve more objects
- simple looking operations (`OrderBy`, for example) can be *really very expensive*
- but then... in most cases, *that doesn't matter*, and the readability is the winner
- but then... in some cases, *that does matter* :)

---

IF WE ASSUME THAT THIS IS IN-MEMORY DATA (LINQ-Objects) - something like `IEnumerable<Person>`, `List<Person>`, `Person[]`, etc:

Note that sorting is a relatively expensive operation, and when using LINQ that also usually means creating a copy of the data (so as not to change the source). There *are* external extension methods available that do this more efficiently within the LINQ concept, i.e.

```cs
Person oldestPerson = people.MaxBy(x => x.Age);
```

Again, not *quite* as efficient as the loop, but *tons* more efficient than `OrderByDescending`+`FirstOrDefault`... just watch out how this behaves for empty inputs (it might throw rather than returning `null`).

---

However, as Dzyann observes in the comments: `people` here could be an `IQueryable<Person>` - something like a `DbSet<Person>` from EF or LINQ-to-SQL (etc), in which case *everything changes*: now we're talking about queries that get pushed down to an external resource, in which case the `OrderByDescending` + `FirstOrDefault` could become SQL like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM People
ORDER BY Age DESC
```

and we've become a hero. If we did that via `foreach` over an `IQueryable<Person>`, we would have issued:

```
SELECT *
FROM People
```

then fetched *everything* over the network as we iterate locally to see which is oldest.

Comment: I would like to point out that depending on what the underlying collection is, actually the order by could be faster. If you have to bring all the persons to memory from a far away server, to then iterate through them to decide which one is older, compared to a SQL Server Sort/Top and then only retrieving the 1 Person. It is funny though that the OP said the second method, which seems faster, is the wrong one. Maybe his coworkers were thinking of something related with ORMs.

Comment: @Dzyann yes, you're right; if this is an `IQueryable<Person>`, then `foreach` is *terrible*

Comment: Yes that is the reason I was thinking maybe why he said the "second one" was the incorrect one.

Comment: @Dzyann notes added; anything I missed?

Comment: Yes I think it is everything, because I think "foreach (Person person in people)" will become a Select * as you said and not many separate selects that could be way worse even. But it is hard to tell without really knowing what that "person" object is.

Answer (score -2):

One of the things about LINQ queries that isn't immediately obvious is that they tend to "fail fast". That is, they exit the loop as soon as the specified criteria is met, rather than iterating over the entire sequence.

For example, `FirstOrDefault()` gets the first item from the sequence and exits immediately, if there are any items in the sequence. If there aren't any, it immediately returns null. It does not iterate over the sequence.

Your `for` loop, however, iterates over each element in the sequence. If the sequence is very large, this can be time consuming. Further, if your exit condition is wrong or missing altogether, you may return the wrong element (although that can happen in LINQ expressions as well).

LINQ expressions are very efficient, retrieving only the data that is necessary to fulfill the request as fast as possible. It's unlikely you'll write a more efficient `for` loop (though not impossible).

Comment: slight caveat here: `OrderByDescending` is a buffering operation - so: before *it* can yield the first input, it needs to consume and process *the entire* input; so... the note on "fail fast" vs iterating over each element isn't quite true... in fact, `OrderByDescending` is *many times* less efficient than the simple loop (I want to say `O(N log N)` vs `O(N)`)

Comment: LINQ expressions are often the most efficient implementation *of the exact operation they're documented to perform*.  So in this case, if you *actually* needed to order all of the items in the sequence based on a projection, you could trust `OrderBy` to do a good job of being about as efficient as it can be.  But they *don't* actually need that.  They need the max value, which, as mentioned, there are much better implementations of.  LINQ makes it easy to use a more expensive operation than you need, as happened here, in addition to making it easy to use those operations when you need them.

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree. That's why I said "*tend* to fail fast."